# How to use python Mock to verify an member variable was set and unset?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Here's a very simplified version of what I'd like to do.  Suppose I have a class:

```
class Paint():
    def __init__(self):
        # None, or a string.
        self.color = None

    def brush(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
        self.color = None
```

Then in my unit tests, I'd like to do the following:

```
p = Paint()
p.brush()

# Hypothetical verification
assert tuples = p.color.mock_assignments
assert tuples[0] == 'blue'
assert tuples[1] == None
```

I'd like to make a real Paint() object, but mock out the member variable `color`.
I want to verify that when calling brush(), that `color` was set to some value and then set back to None.  How do I do this?

I am on ubuntu 18.04, python 3.7, using mock package.

Thanks.

Comment: In your real code, so you have any function calls (from internal modules, or external libs) between `self.color = 'blue'` and `self.color = None`? If so, can you update your example?

Comment: I just have a paint object.  And some other code calls p.brush().  I want to create a unit test for brush(), and verify that the attribute is set to a specific value, then unset.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. This is why i asked what other calls you make change the `self.color` value.

Here is what I had in mind:
```
def brush(self):
    self.color = 'blue'
    some_function(self.color)
    self.color = None
```
If you are using something that makes a call in between the two lines you have under your `brush()` function, you can mock "some function", and assert that it was called.

Comment: I see.  Nice trick, but unfortunately, it's won't work, the original brush function is highly branched with a couple of inner functions.  I can boil down the function to making sure that an attribute set to a specific value, and then set back to None.This will verify that it works in a meaningful way.  While I like your mock a function in between trick, I have issues with it.  It doesn't really test the meaning of the function, and also, if future changes removes or renames the function but keeps its meaning, then it will break the test.

Comment: From the perspective of clean code, you should avoid having nested structures. It increases the complexity, and introduces coupling, and makes harder to test. You may wish to review the complexity of your code, but this should be a separate issue.

Why do you need your function to have a class attribute set? It doesn't seem right. If the live time of the `color` variable is short-lived, don't make it instance level, but only scope it to the function, and pass it as an argument between any method calls.

Expand your example to demonstrate the complexity.

Comment: yes.  I am in agreement with inner functions.  Unfortunately, I am not the original author of the code, nor can I make drastic refactor changes to it, b/c author will disapprove.  Such is the life of a corporate agile programmer.

Comment: Well, the original function 'color' is really an asyncio.Task, and the inner functions manipulate the task in asynchronous fashion.  It really is ugly.  Trying to come up with a better example and stay true to the original code may be more difficulty than it's worth.  I just wish for answer to my original question.  b/c if it can be done, it will really solve my testing problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218119/discussion-between-sazzy-and-bitdiot).

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion, here is a mock I would do with such case.

I have modified your code, assumed another function is used to utilise the changed `self.color` value.

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def some_function(arg):
    # emulates another function that does something
    print(arg)

class Paint():
    def __init__(self):
        # None, or a string.
        self.color = None

    def brush(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
        # assumed function that is called with the changed attribute
        some_function(self.color)
        self.color = None

# unittest way
class TestPaint(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch(f'{__name__}.some_function')
    def test_brush(self, mock_fun):
        p = Paint()
        p.brush()
        mock_fun.assert_called_with('blue')
        self.assertEqual(p.color, None)

# pytest way
@patch(f'{__name__}.some_function')
def test_pain(mock_fun):
    p = Paint()
    p.brush()
    mock_fun.assert_called_with('blue')
    assert p.color is None
```